# Still render the page if the components code has error - React/Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I haven't got much experience in React, would really appreciate any advice.
My situation is that:

- I have a dynamic page let say the url is mysite/[productid]
- The page is the combination of component A, B and C
- There is an error happened in component B and React render 404 page which I don't want to.

My question is:
Is there any way in React/Nextjs to still render the page (the page still displays without the error component) if one the components scratch, and log the error using Sentry? As I know there is a way to do that with Emberjs.

I do not want to render another error page with error boundary as it does not make sense to take down whole page with only one error component.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

There are two solutions to handling errors in a React application:

- [JavaScript Exception Handling i.e. `try/catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling#try...catch_statement)
- [React Error Boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html)

If a component can recover from an error internally, then the expressions which may throw that error should be wrapped in a `try/catch` block. Otherwise, you can use React Error Boundaries to manage any errors in child components.